# How to copy changing substring in string?

Tags: python

How can I copy data from changing string?

I tried to slice, but length of slice is changing.

For example in one case I should copy number 128 from string `'"edge_liked_by":{"count":128}'`, in another I should copy 15332 from `"edge_liked_by":{"count":15332}`

Comment: Please post your code and sample output you're getting

Comment: Are you trying to parse JSON by string manipulation? Your string looks like a JSON fragment. This is almost certainly the wrong way to go about your task.

Comment: If the format is in JSON as in your example, you could get away with it parsing. Otherwise, you need to use regular expressions

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is JSON. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the type of string you are working with is read from [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), maybe you are getting it as the output of some API you are working with?

If it is JSON, you've probably gone one step too far in atomizing it to a string like this. I'd work with the original output, if possible, if I were you.

If not, to make it more JSON like, I'd convert it to JSON by wrapping it in `{}`, and then working with the `json.loads` module.

```py
import json

string = '"edge_liked_by":{"count":15332}'
string = "{"+string+"}"
json_obj = json.loads(string)
count = json_obj['edge_liked_by']['count']
```

`count` will have the desired output. I prefer this option to using regular expressions because you can rely on the structure of the data and reuse the code in case you wish to parse out other attributes, in a very intuitive way. With regular expressions, the code you use will change if the data are decimal, or negative, or contain non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re

string = '"edge_liked_by":{"count":15332}'
number = re.search(r'{"count":(\d*)}', string).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on the situation, however I find regular expressions to be useful.

To grab the numbers from the string without caring about their location, you would do as follows:

```
import re
def get_string(string):
    return re.search(r'\d+', string).group(0)

>>> get_string('"edge_liked_by":{"count":128}')
'128'
```

To only get numbers from the *end of the string, you can use an anchor to ensure the result is pulled from the far end. The following example will grab any sequence of unbroken numbers that is both preceeded by a colon and ends within 5 characters of the end of the string:

```
import re
def get_string(string):
    rval = None
    string_match = re.search(r':(\d+).{0,5}$', string)
    if string_match:
        rval = string_match.group(1)
    return rval

>>> get_string('"edge_liked_by":{"count":128}')
'128'
>>> get_string('"edge_liked_by":{"1321":1}')
'1'
```

In the above example, adding the colon will ensure that we only pick values and don't match keys such as the `"1321"` that I added in as a test.

If you just want anything after the last colon, but excluding the bracket, try combining split with slicing:

```
>>> '"edge_liked_by":{"count":128}'.split(':')[-1][0:-1]
'128'
```

Finally, considering this looks like a JSON object, you can add curly brackets to the string and treat it as such. Then it becomes a nested dict you can query:

```
>>> import json
>>> string = '"edge_liked_by":{"count":128}'
>>> string = '{' + string + '}'
>>> string = json.loads(string)
>>> string.get('edge_liked_by').get('count')
128
```

The first two will return a string and the final one returns a number due to being treated as a JSON object.

Comment: Searching just for digits anywhere might be unsafe. Since the keys seem arbitrary, you probably can't exclude the possibility that the key itself contains a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

```
a='"edge_liked_by":{"count":128}'

import re

b=re.findall(r'\d+', a)[0]

b
Out[16]: '128'
```

Comment: Searching just for digits anywhere might be unsafe. Since the keys seem arbitrary, you probably can't exclude the possibility that the key itself contains a digit.  You know, if you choose to use regex, which I think is a good choice for such problems, then why don't you just make it a big sharper?!